# ruamel yaml cloning a node without merging anchors

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file with a similar structure:

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
```

What I'm trying to achieve is cloning the node `dev` by performing a deep copy of all its properties - including the merge operator - and changing its name to `stage`.
The desired result is the following:

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test

stage:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
```

I've tried doing this using `ruamel.yaml` library by running the following code snippet:

```
import copy
import sys

import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test

"""

def main():
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
    original_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_str)

    copied_stanza = copy.deepcopy(original_yaml['dev'])

    original_yaml['stage'] = copied_stanza

    yaml.dump(original_yaml, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However I get the following result:

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test

stage:
  <<:
    key1: test
    key2: test

  key3: test

  key1: test
  key2: test
```

which is different from what I want since it's flattening the merge operator in a very weird way.

I believe the issue is the way I'm copying the node, however I've tried searching the web for hours and tried a plethora of different approaches without any luck.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

After Anthon's answer, I was able to get closer to the desired result.
However if the node that I'm trying to copy has one more level of depth (see `dev.key4` in this example):

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
  key4:
    subkey1: test
```

then the generated yaml will start creating anchors and aliases for all those nested nodes:

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
  key4: &id001
    subkey1: test

stage:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
  key4: *id001
```

How can I avoid the creation of those?

**UPDATE 2**

I adapted the solution provided by Anthon to handle any level of depth using a recursive function:

```
import sys

import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
  key4:
    subkey1: test

"""


def create_copied_stanza(dev):
    copied_stanza = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
    for k, v in dev.items():
        if k in dev._ok:
            if isinstance(v, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):  # Add your condition here
                copied_stanza[k] = create_copied_stanza(v)
            else:
                copied_stanza[k] = v
    return copied_stanza

def main():
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
    original_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_str)
    dev = original_yaml['dev']
    copied_stanza = create_copied_stanza(dev)
    copied_stanza._yaml_merge = dev._yaml_merge
    original_yaml['stage'] = copied_stanza
    yaml.dump(original_yaml, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The mappings in your YAML are loaded as `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` instances and they
have `__deepcopy__` implemented just so as to preserve the merge key.

To get what you want you currently need to copy the keys owned by the
mapping and the attribute that contains the merge information.
Make sure to pin your `ruamel.yaml` version as these internals might change
in the future.

```py
import sys

import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test

"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
original_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_str)
dev = original_yaml['dev']
copied_stanza = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap({k: v for k, v in dev.items() if k in dev._ok})
copied_stanza._yaml_merge = dev._yaml_merge
original_yaml['stage'] = copied_stanza
yaml.dump(original_yaml, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
main: &base
  key1: test
  key2: test

dev:
  <<: *base
  key3: test

stage:
  <<: *base
  key3: test
```

If your merge key is not at the root level, you have to make a function that does this for you, recursing in
any mappings,
but for your YAML this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However this is not the result that I'm looking for as the merge key for the copied stanza is not preserved. Is it possible to achieve the result shown in the second code block of my question? I guess that's what you were trying to say in your second to last paragraph. Can you provide some more insight into how to build such a function?

Comment: Sorry, I did look if you also presented what you wanted, but did not scroll up enough to see that. I updated the answer, now it looks more like what you expect.

Comment: Hi Anthon, thanks for taking the time to update your answer. It actually works, but when I have a yaml with one more level of depth, it will start creating anchors and aliases (see the UPDATE section in my question).
Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Updated the original question with a possible solution to the problem. It works for my use case (max 1 level of depth) and should technically work for any level of depth.